# CSS fixed div within container

Tags: css

How do I have fixed div contained within a div.container, where the fixed div is ONLY fixed within the div.container (and not the rest of the page)? That means if I scroll down the page, outside of the container div, the fixed div does not scroll. It's hard to explain, see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jg8qJ/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

give

```
.container { 
    position:relative; 
}
```

and set

```
.info { 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: @user2745266 Start a new question and provide your example.