# Positioning a Fixed div inside another does not work

Tags: html, css

A related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076992/css-fixed-div-within-container) and the answer does not work for me. In brief there are 2 columns left and right. And the right column have a children `<div>` or `<section>` or something. When the page is scrolled, the children must not scroll or move. Adding `position: absolute` to the child lets the child to scroll along with the page. And `position:fixed` making the child to appear at screen's extreme left or right and screen top depending on `right:0` or `left:0`. How to make this fixed inside the right column?

The JSFIDDLE is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5wM4V/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify  `.right-inner` class as follows to get the desired result

```
.right-inner{
position: fixed;
margin-right: 5%;
text-align: middle;    
}
```

see the updated [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/5wM4V/34/)

Comment: As per your code the `right-inner` is now fixed with respect to the page not the right column. http://fiddle.jshell.net/5wM4V/23/show/

Comment: remove left and top. Then you will push it to the right using margin-left, to position it in the right position you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 0, the value of `.right`'s left-position should be (at least) the value of the width of the left column

for example:

```
.right{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 360px;
}
```

You don't need the wrapper for .right, so I've elliminated it in this fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ynMYm/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.outer{
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
}
.left{
    width: 350px;
    border-right: 1px solid #555;
    float: left;
}
.right{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin-left:350px;
    position: fixed;
}
.right-inner{
    position: fixed;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5wM4V/42/

Full screen view: http://jsfiddle.net/5wM4V/42/embedded/result/